# Call a function without really calling the function?

Tags: python

I know my question sounds weird, but I am searching for this but I can't find it nowhere. I want to simulate a TableScan statement from SQL with printing out a list of lists, so I call the method next() with the object 'x' as long as ("EOF" of list) is not returned. But if I write 
`while(x.next() != "EOF"):` the function next() is already called once and this not what I want, because I skip already one tuple.

Here the code:

```
class TableScan(Iterator):
  def __init__(self, collection):
    super().__init__()
    self.collection = collection
    self.iter = None

  def open(self):
    self.iter = iter(self.collection)

  def next(self):
    try:
      while(self.iter != None):
        return next(self.iter)
    except StopIteration:
      return "EOF"

# The list.
cS = [[101,2,3,5,1],
       [202,4,99,2,4],
       [303,2,4,6,8],
       [404,1,23,4,6],
       [505,2,22,4,5]]

# Making object x and calling constructor of class TableScan.
x = TableScan(cS)
while(x.next() != "EOF"):         ###Problem- lines###
  print(x.next())
```

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the result to a variable so you can test it and print it.

```
while True:
    n = x.next()
    if n == 'EOF':
        break
    print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

i know this has an answer, but in python 3.8 and above you can do:

```
while (n := x.next()) != 'EOF':
    print(n)
```